# StreamReader и переменная в цикле while в C#

Tags: c#, циклы, поток-ввода

Если создать текстовый файл Test:

```
Петя
Вася
Ваня
```

и написать такой код:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            StreamReader a = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Test.txt");
            string line;
            while ((line = a.ReadLine) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

, то на консоль выведутся все 3 имени, а если написать такой код:

```
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    namespace Test
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main()
            {
                StreamReader a = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Test.txt");
                while (a.ReadLine != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

, то выведется только Вася. Почему такая разница? Что делает программа во втором случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReadLine()` читает из файла одну строку.

На строчке `while (a.ReadLine() != null)` будет прочитана первая строка.
На строчке `Console.WriteLine(a.ReadLine())` — вторая. Именно она и будет напечатана.
Затем снова будет прочитана строка в `while`, цикл будет продолжен, но следующий вызов `WrieteLine` напечатает уже пустую строку, потому что `ReadLine()` вернёт `null`.

Настоящая проблема здесь в том, что `ReadLine()` это *метод с побочным эффектом*, поэтому его нельзя вызывать два или три раза и рассчитывать, что он вернёт тот же самый результат. Первый способ это стандартный подход в таких случаях: вызываем один раз, сохраняем в переменную, и затем проверяем уже её.